# KSQL : How can I change separator (comma) of DELIMITED FORMAT?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I try to put a big number of messages (350M) to customer topic (source topic) with value format like this

```
10957402000||10965746672||2|2756561822|452048703649890|8984048701003649890
```

and then I make some streams and table on that topic, but the delimited format supported by ksql is just comma separator. I have some questions:

- Is there any way to config ksql can understand my format? Or I have to convert to format default by ksql (comma separator)
- From the original value from source topic like above, how this command can mapping value to table column? Or I have to convert format to json?
  CREATE STREAM  (sub_id BIGINT, contract_id BIGINT, cust_id BIGINT, account_id BIGINT,telecom_service_id BIGINT, isdn BIGINT, imsi BIGINT) \
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='customer', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

*Edit 26 February 2021* ksqlDB now supports configurable delimiters - use the `VALUE_DELIMITER` (or `KEY_DELIMITER`) configuration option. For example:

```sql
CREATE STREAM (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR) 
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED', VALUE_DELIMITER='TAB')
```

---

Original answer:

Currently KSQL only supports comma-separated for `DELIMITED` value format. So you'll need to use commas, or JSON, or Avro, for your source data.

Comment: Thanks, you are my hero :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to mark answers as correct, if they are :)

Comment: Can you recommend for me what format best for big data (~ 1 billion messages/topic)?

Comment: I'd recommend Avro, because you benefit from the Schema Registry then, and the message size in Kafka is smaller.